# Android GPS on or off state

Tags: android, gps, toggle, state, android-manifest

Is there any way to check if the Android GPS is on or off without any permission, just the state I don't need to toggle it.

Thanks

Answer (score 38, accepted):

No. Checking GPS Status on Android requires

```
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
```

The code to check the status of GPS

```
 LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );
 boolean statusOfGPS = manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

Comment: ditto. AFAI can see all of the methods that could tell you about the enabled / disabled or anything about the state of the gps requires the appropriate permissions. Seems like you should be able to check the enabled/disabled state without needing permission.

Comment: This checks if GPS is ENABLED or not. Not whether or not it is actually on. This may be what the OP was asking for but there is an important distinction. If it is enabled, then you can ask for GPS location rather than network location but you have to remember to turn GPS back off.

Answer (score 6):

steps -

1. Create services running in backgroud
2. You require following permission in Manifest file too -

   ```
   android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
   ```
3. write code

   ```
    final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService    (Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );

   if ( !manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) )

   //what you want to do
    else

      //what you want to do
   ```
4. Or simply you can check

   ```
   LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );
   boolean statusOfGPS = manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
   ```
5. run your services continuous to monitor connection
6. call your services from Activity

Answer (score 4):

If you want to check the condition of GPS that whether it is ON or OFF, then this solution will help you

```
final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );

if ( !manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) )
  Toast.makeText(context, "GPS is disable!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
else
 Toast.makeText(context, "GPS is Enable!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```