# Get Current Position in Google Map when Click on Android Button

Tags: android, google-maps

I implement map in my device successfully.
 but now I want to add functionality
 When I click on Button then I want to get Current Location in map.
How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add listener on button click.

```
Button btnMyLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMyLocation); 
CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = null;

btnMyLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Location loc = map.getMyLocation();
                if (loc != null) {
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(), loc
                            .getLongitude());
                    cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 17);
                    map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);

                }

            }
        });
```

for GPS :

You require following permission in Manifest file

```
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
```

and here is code :

```
final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );

  if ( !manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) )
    Toast.makeText(context, "GPS is disable!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
  else
    Toast.makeText(context, "GPS is Enable!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: what is  animateCameraToMarker?

Comment: and How to check my Device GPS is on or off?

Comment: For Reference Check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300572/android-gps-on-or-off-state

Answer (score 0):

Just start a location Update listener on the click of that button. and when new location arrives move the camera in mapObject (got in OnMapReady() method) to that location with animations.

Answer (score 0):

In the OnClick method, get the currentGPS location (latitude longitude co-ordinates) through LocationManager. More info on howto is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

i have a similar trouble, in my case work with this:

```
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude()), 4));
```

Regards